# Site doesn't display correctly in IE

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I know it is not a new question but I can't find an answer in previously asked questions.
This is one of first sites I've build (using a tutorial). So I don't have a good knowledge of HTML.

i checked the site using validator en removed some errors (still some warnings left) but according to that site it seems ok. (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=caenenbvba.be&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&outline=1&group=0&verbose=1&st=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.606)

In firefox, google chrome, safari it works fine.
can you guys help me?

website: http://www.caenenbvba.be

thanks in advance.

DD

Comment: It's IE. What do you expect?

Comment: Which version of IE do you have?

Comment: It works in IE version 10 but anything lower doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

im not %100 but im pretty sure internet explorer doesn't support all new features with HTML5 and css3. i have a website and one page doesn't  work because its got the newest CSS3 features on it.

Comment: some pages of the site work and other not, and they use the same CCS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's not in compatibility mode

Comment: i've check it and its nog in compatibility mode.